# Finding source code of the Tor metrics site

Tags: directory, consensus

Hello I'm creating my own private tor network for me and my friends but I was wondering does anyone know where I can find the source code of the tor metric site? It would be really nice if I could see how my nodes are doing instead of having to look at a command line

Answer (score 0):

Well, you better use - actually - the original network, sharding **is** the key to vulnerability. You can make a VPN hop-network to yourselves, which is an easy task for OpenVPN, but you will be protected by the number of nodes. If you're making a separate network - you'll still be vulnerable to the nature of the Directory Services. If you need more info - just drop me a line!

Answer (score 0):

The Tor Metrics website and related repositories can be found at https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/network-health/metrics, but there are a lot of pieces involved in making it run. For example the data collection is separate from the website itself. It would probably be fairly complicated to get all of the Tor Metrics website running for a private network.